# MonoDevelop - using Subversion 1.7 on a Mac

Tags: macos, svn, mono, monodevelop

I have homebrew installed, and was able to upgrade subversion to 1.7 using it (and moving /usr/local/bin ahead of /usr/bin in my PATH).

So if I type:

```
svn help
Subversion command-line client, version 1.7.6.
```

The problem is MonoDevelop doesn't seem to use the svn in the PATH, because svn 1.7 repos don't appear to be versioned in MonoDevelop.

I need 1.7 because I also use a VM with Windows and I share repos between the host and guest.  On Windows I used TortoiseSVN/AnkhSvn which target subversion 1.7.

Is there a way to get MonoDevelop to use svn in a different location?  I tried playing with MonoDevelop.VersionControl.Subversion.Unix.dll.config, but couldn't get it to work:

```
<configuration>
    <dllmap os="osx" dll="libsvn_client-1.so.0" target="libsvn_client-1.dylib" />
    <dllmap os="osx" dll="libapr-0.so.0" target="libapr-1.0.dylib" />
    <dllmap os="freebsd" dll="libapr-0.so.0" target="libapr-1.so" />
</configuration>
```

I tried creating a symbolic link in the same dir as the Subversion dll:

```
libsvn_client-1.dylib -> /usr/local/Cellar/subversion/1.7.6/lib/libsvn_client-1.dylib
```

Comment: +1 Subversion 1.7 is *still* not working in MD. Related: [bug report](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1491). Comment by Xamarin dev: ["Updating to svn 1.7 is a fair bit of work. It's something I hope to do over the
next few weeks/months but there is no ETA on this yet."](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=5525#c3)

Comment: They changed alot between 1.6 and 1.7, so I'm guessing libsvn has changes too, which is the problem. I am annoyed that moving folders can break things in 1.6--I am so used to using 1.7 on Windows.

Answer (score 2):

Try to start monodevelop with MONO's debugging enabled, that is use something like:

```
export MONO_LOG_LEVEL=debug; export MONO_LOG_MASK=dll; mono MonoDevelop.exe
```

That should give you some information about exactly where mono is trying to find the subversion library.

Comment: That is definitely logging things, but MonoDevelop won't boot up all the way, it can't seem to find _any_ libraries when run directly like this.  What directory should I try this from?

Comment: Given that you are on a Mac try executing something like:
MONO_LOG_LEVEL=debug; MONO_LOG_MASK=dll; /Applications/MonoDevelop.app/Contents/MacOS/MonoDevelop

Comment: It will fail with a lot of loads because it is searching in different places. But dump the output and search for libsvn

Comment: If I `grep -i` (ignore case) for `svn` or `subversion`, I don't see those at all in the output.

Comment: Maybe try without the log mask and see what else is going on regarding libsvn

Comment: Well, I tried using a blank for `MONO_LOG_MASK` and got no output, then I tried `MONO_LOG_MASK=all`, and got more output than `dll`, but none related to libsvn.

Comment: That sounds very strange, im not using SVN myself in MonoDevelop so im out of good ideas :-(