# Monodevelop SVN 1.7 support

Tags: svn, mono, monodevelop

I'm trying to checkout an SVN repo and it does get checked out, however the solution does not appear under source control. I then tried to simply open an already checked out folder and I do not get versioning support either.

I tried this in both Windows and Linux with no success with MonoDevelop 3.0.4 and 3.0.5

My guess is that since the .sln file is in the path /trunk/code/project/project.sln and the new 1.7 format keeps only one ".svn" folder at the top of the checked out folder (e.g. /home/gustavo/ProjectSrc/ ) hence MD not "finding" the versioned code.

Anybody has had success using SVN 1.7 and MonoDevelop?

Comment: Related topics: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1491#c6 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12444081/monodevelop-using-subversion-1-7-on-a-mac

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Bug 1491 - Support for SVN 1.7](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1491) confirms missing support of SVN 1.7 in MonoDevelop. You have to checkout WC with 1.6 client